# TreeMap -- How to find the number of words that begin with each letter of the alphabet

Tags: java, list, loops, dictionary, treemap

So I have a list of words. For example, {Apple, Available, Art, Between, Beyond, Door, Drive, ......}

and I want to show the number of words that begin with each letter of the alphabet, so the outcome should be like A = 3, B = 2, D = 2, ......

Here is the code I wrote, but apparently it didn't work like the way I wanted.

```
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < theWords.length; i++) {
        for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
            int numOfWords = 0;
            char firstLetter = theWords[i].charAt(0);
            if (firstLetter == alphabet) {
                myMap.put(String.valueOf(alphabet), numOfWords + 1);
            }
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(myMap);
```

And this is the outcome I got ...

```
{A=1, B=1, C=1, D=1, E=1, F=1, G=1, H=1, J=1, K=1, L=1, M=1, N=1, O=1, P=1, Q=1, R=1, S=1, T=1, U=1, W=1, Y=1}
```

P.S. I have to use TreeMap.

Comment: Every time you iterate through your inner for loop you set numOfwords to 0. It's never going to be more than 0 +1 in your inner if statement.

Comment: Use For-Each , it's easier to read your code that way.                          `for(String word: theWords) { }`

Comment: Map maps key with value, where key is unique. 1. Create a map, 2. For Each word in list, fetch the first character 3. See if fetched character is present in the keyset of the map 4. If present then just increment the count for that key else make a new entry in the map and keep count as 1. For your problem, you can simply take an array of type `int` of size 26. This will act your map. 0th index is for `A`, 1st index is for `B` and so on till 25th index for `Z`. Now apply the aobove logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the double loop, you can get the first character and add to the Map.

Something akin to:

```
for (String fruit : theFruits) {
  String firstLetter = fruit.substring(0, 1);
  Integer count = myMap.get(firstLetter);
  if (count == null) {
    myMap.put(firstLetter, 1);
  }
  else {
    myMap.put(firstLetter, ++count);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this may be true, I think the OP is struggling with learning basic coding concepts and has made a logical error. I don't know that improving on their technique is helpful here as they really need to understand their mistake.

Comment: @leigero, I understand your point. However, I think the double loop is confusing the issue. The goal is to get the first letter of the word, and increment a counter in the Map. The extra loop clouds the logic. So, reducing the clutter makes the approach more understandable, IMHO.

Comment: @HT0000, glad it helped. You may wish to consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

you set `int numOfWords = 0;` in the inner loop - that is the case.
That's why it's always `1` put in the map

Answer (score 0):

Map maps key with value, where key is unique.

1. Create a map.
2. For Each word in list, fetch the first character.
3. See if fetched character is present in the keyset of the map.
4. If present then just increment the count for that key else make a new entry in the map and keep count as 1.

For your problem, you can simply take an array of type `int` of size 26. This will act as your map.

0th index is for `a`, 1st index is for `b` and so on till 25th index for `z`.

Now apply the above logic

for example if the word list is

```
String[] wordList = { "apple", "mango", "berry", "rice", "banana"} ;

int [] map = new int [26]; //by default all elements initialized with 0
for(int i =0; i < wordList.length; i++){
     char first = wordList[i].charAt(0);
     int index = first - 'a';
     map[index] = map[index] + 1;
}
```

Assumptions :  words are in small case and each word only consists of 26 English alphabets in small case and all words are unique. In case of additional characters size of array will need to be modified and for duplicates array can be replaced with Hashmap but algo steps remains the same as mentioned above

P.S. Usually for prefix searches Trie is preferred solution.